# Collision detection of each side not working

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, game-physics

I've been recently working on a 2D platformer that has multiple characters you can change between. I wanted to implement collision detection that cycles through each character and depending on which side they're touching stop it from moving. Basically so the characters could jump on top of one another and couldn't pass through each other. I used an AABB Intersect collision detection system and then to determine which side of the character I've hit I've used this code:

```js
for (var a = 0; a < this.characters.length; a++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < this.characters.length; b++) {
    if (a !== b) {
      if (this.characters[a].collision(this.characters[b])) {
        var ab = this.characters[a].y + this.characters[a].height,
          ar = this.characters[a].x + this.characters[a].width,
          bb = this.characters[b].y + this.characters[b].height,
          br = this.characters[b].x + this.characters[b].width;

        var tc = ab - this.characters[b].y,

          bc = bb - this.characters[a].y,

          lc = ar - this.characters[b].x,

          rc = br - this.characters[a].x;

        // Bottom is touching something
        if (tc < bc && tc < lc && tc < rc) {
          this.characters[a].isJumping = false;
          this.characters[a].vel.y = 0;
          this.characters[a].y = this.characters[b].y - this.characters[a].height;
        }

        // Top is touching something
        if (bc < tc && bc < lc && bc < rc) {
          this.characters[a].isJumping = false;
          this.characters[a].y = this.characters[b].y + this.characters[b].height;
        }

        // Right side is touching something
        if (lc < rc && lc < tc && lc < bc) {
          this.characters[a].x = this.characters[b].x - this.characters[a].width;
        }

        // Left side is touching something
        if (rc < lc && rc < tc && rc < bc) {
          this.characters[a].x = this.characters[b].x + this.characters[b].width;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It appears to work fine for the first character (block; I didn't mention this, but, all of the characters are squares) but this system glitches if the I attempt to use the second character (the characters are in an array) and test the collision on the first character. Things such as the jumping on top of not working and the walking left into the character causing the first character to move left (I know why that's happening, but, I'm not sure how to fix it). The third character doesn't work for the first two and then by the fourth it's complete chaos. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think you could check if the character is colliding with something at all and if it is a character or block do that code.

Answer (score 0):

A single collision will cause two hits in your loop, first when `a = 0` and the collided object `b = 1` (for example), and then when `a = 1` and `b = 0`, the same collision will be detected again.

I think it's better to have an array of inactive characters that you check against one active character.

You can create those variables at the moment the player switches characters. This way you only need a single loop and you don't need the `if a != b` check

This code illustrates the idea:

```
function characterChange(){
   activeCharacter = objA;
   inActiveCharacters = [objB, objC, objD];
}

function checkCollisions(){
   for(let i = 0; i<inActiveCharacters.length; i++){
      checkHit(activeCharacter, inActiveCharacters[i]);
   }
}

function checkHit(a,b) {
    // your a b check here
}
```

Comment: I did that before. But, what if I needed collision detection between inactive characters? Is there a way to do that?